# Is it possible to change grayed out permissions on Android?

Tags: security, permissions, updates, android-11, android-api-30

A certain *Security app* is basically questioning a good set of my apps permissions on my device. The *Security app* is asking me to change permissions. But this message pops up on some of my apps.

*If you deny this permission, basic features of your device may no longer function as intended.*

However I can't because the permissions I want are grayed out. My phone is not rooted. Unless I use a *terminal*, but don't know how.

P.S.
My phone Android 11 is no longer receiving security updates.

Version:       11

Version Name:   R

API Level:     30

Build ID:      RPIA.201005.004.A1

Thank you